# How to download a locally stored file in VueJS

Tags: html, csv, download, vue.js

I have an upload system and I am trying to supply a sample template for users. I have a template stored locally in a subfolder in assets, I would like to access that in my VueJS component and display a link to it on the page. These are the applicaple parts of the file structure:

```
├──app
│  └──Components
│     └──Uploader.vue
└──assets
   └──files
      └──Template_Upload.csv
```

In Uploader.vue I have this line:

```
<a v-bind:href="item.loc" download>{{item.title}}</a>
```

And in the export I have this line

```
data() {
  return {
    item: {title: 'Upload Template', loc: require('../../assets/files/Template_Upload.csv')}
}
```

This method works if I have an image. Upon clicking on the link, it downloads the image. However, if I use a .csv or a .xlsx file, errors are thrown upon opening the page. I've tried using

```
import fileTemplate from "../../assets/files/FileTemplate.csv";
```

As well, and using *fileTemplate* as the *loc* property. This also works if I use a picture. But I'm not able to bring in a document. Is this a limitation I can't get past or is there a different method I can try?

I've also gone into Visual Studio (in other words, the .csproj file), and set the Template_Upload.csv *Build Action* setting is set to "Content" and the *Copy to Ouput Directory* setting is set to "Copy Always".

These are the resources I have primarily used thus far:

> [How to import and use image in a Vue single file component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116796/how-to-import-and-use-image-in-a-vue-single-file-component)
>
> [What are the various "Build action" settings in Visual Studio project properties and what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties)

Comment: You need a CSV loader. Other options include making your web server serve that directory and then the `loc` would just be a typical link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks OverCoder, the solution was indeed to add a CSV Loader in order that adds the locally stored files to the webpack server. For anyone else using webpack, I added this module to my webpack.config.js file:

```js
{
    test: /\.(csv|xlsx|xls)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: `files/[name].[ext]`
    }
}
```

Then I could reference the file easily like this in my template,

```
<a href="/files/Template_Upload.csv" download>File Template</a>
```

or this

```
<a :href="item.loc" download>File Template</a>
```

using the same data return as I said. Using the require statement with the loader puts the "required" files into the wwwroot/files folder when the project builds. Thanks again, OverCoder, this saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This is a bit obscure. What require statement? What is the exact folder structure it can see? The project I am working on is already quite sizeable and I am not sure I can just add any `assets` folder anywhere I'd like.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone which doesnt want to use webpack, I solved this issue:

- create a folder called `files` in `public`
- I moved there the files I wanted to download
  and Voila, WORKED.

[image]
 `<a href="/files/book.pdf" download>DOWNLOAD</a>`

Comment: this works flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

Just an extension to the [@Judd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028158/7469302). If you don't have a `webpack.config.js`, you can use the `vue.config.js` file. (just create it in the root, if it doesn't exist)

vue.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(csv|xlsx|xls)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: `files/[name].[ext]`
          }
        }
      ],
     },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me;

```
<a href="../../assets/files/FileTemplate.csv" download>Download</a>
```

It behaves nicely even in dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

I was on Laravel, and I follow [this tuto](https://coffeequery.com/posts/file-upload-download-and-delete-in-vuejs-and-laravel) to get mine working:

1. create an FileController, add a download method

```
public function downloadFile($file){
   $path = public_path().'/app/upload-folder/'.$file; // or storage_path() if needed
   $header = [
       'Content-Type' => 'application/*',
   ];
   return response()->download($path, $file, $header);
}
```

2. create an api entry point in `api.php`

```
Route::get('download/upload-folder/{file}', 'FileController@downloadFile');
```

3. create a method which uses axios

```
async downloadTemplateFile(file){
    axios.get('/download/template/file/'+file, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(res=>{
      let blob = new Blob([res.data], {type:'application/*'})
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = file
      link._target = 'blank'
      link.click();
    })
  }
```

4. call from vue template

```
<li>Download the CSV template <a href="#" @click="downloadTemplateFile('FileTemplate.csv')">here</a></li>
```

Hope this will helps others ;)

Comment: No, it does not word for word file tried doing that

Answer (score 1):

Place the file you want to download in the public folder as it is the root folder of your application.
File Structure Image ->
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vrjw.png)

Give the href link as below :

```
<a :href="'/files/SampleFile.xlsx'" class="btn btn-primary" download>Sample File</a>
```

You can provide any file in the folder structure. For example : .pdf, .xlsx, .png etc

Please note, give the href as :href with file path as **"** 'your file path' **"**

Tested and Working on Vue3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="../../assets/files/FileTemplate.csv">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and it is with a button:

```
<a href="/files/Template_Upload.csv" download>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</a>
```