# Vue.js props img src binding with webpack alias (@)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

my vue app, make img-src binding with alias. it running direct use.

```
<img src="@/assets/search.png" />
```

But, this code make component, alias not resolve.

```
<template>
  <div class="button-card">
    <img :src="src">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Button Card',
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

With component build result html:

```
<div class="button-card">
  <img src="@/assets/search.png">
  <!-- should be with resolve: src/assets/search.png -->
</div>
```

Webpack alias define config:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    '@': resolve('src'),
  }
},
```

Why this code not resolve? or what can I do to make it run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that should use `data` instead of `props` (you aren't creating a new component and sending the props to it).

You could try with:

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/search.png')" />
```

That is a shorthand for:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import image from "@/assets/search.png"


export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            image: image
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116796/how-to-import-and-use-image-in-a-vue-single-file-component) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/202) you could see how it works and similar problems.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @myazarc if by dynamic you mean from a database than importing or requestion by a resolved path `@` will never work

Comment: @SuperDJ no database, in array for fast loads.

Answer (score 3):

In short, We can alter [transformAssetUrls](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls) option of Vue loader to archive this.

Perhaps it's "a little bit" too late, but I decide to leave this comment for someone like me who encounter the similar issue.

After some search and study, I figure out this is webpack loader's work, [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) to be specifically. As Vue loader is processing template, it would transforms url of certain attributes of certain tags, which can be configured by [transformAssetUrls](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls).

For more detail, you can refer to [Asset URL Handling](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules) of Vue loader.

Comment: Great! There's a configuration example in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/images#vue-cli-3-support)  that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe webpack aliases only work in imports, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias:

> Create aliases to **import** or **require** certain modules more easily. For example, to alias a bunch of commonly used src/ folders:

In your case `@/assets/search.png` is just a plain string.

I guess you could use dynamic `import()` function here, something like: `return () => import(this.src)`.

Comment: thanks, i load dynamic data. i use static <img src="@/assets/search.png" />, working. but with props not resolve, be direct string.

Comment: How about putting your images in a directory that is going to be served directly by your server and just using their url in src. No need to import anything then. Something like <button-card :src="urlToImage">.