# Vue.js + Webpack Requesting Multiple Incorrect Resource URLs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, npm, webpack

I've been using Vue.js single file components to build a website and really enjoying the modular system. I'm running into an issue however where the browser seems to be requesting multiple versions of resources instead of just one URL for each.

`HeaderBar.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="header" :class="{sticky: isSticking }">
        <img id="header-logo" src="../assets/logo/logo_horiz.svg">
        <div id="header-menubox">
            <a class="social-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img src="../assets/social/facebook_blue.svg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img src="../assets/social/twitter_blue.svg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img src="../assets/social/insta_blue.svg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img src="../assets/social/yelp_blue.svg">
            </a>
            <button id="header-menu-button" @click="toggleMenu">
                <img src="../assets/button/menu.svg">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HeaderBar'
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
#header {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 100;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "logo . menu";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#header.sticky {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#header-logo {
    grid-area: logo;
}

#header-menubox {
    grid-area: menu;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
}

#header-menu-button {
    background-color: unset;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2;
}
</style>
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HeaderBar></HeaderBar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderBar from './components/HeaderBar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HeaderBar
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

`vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

Chrome Developer Console
[image: Chrome Console Error Output]

What's causing this behavior?

[EDIT]
I modified the `HeaderBar.vue` to import the images:

```
<template>
    <div id="header" :class="{sticky: isSticking }">
        <img id="header-logo" :src="logoImg">
        <div id="header-menubox">
            <a class="social-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img :src="fbImg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img :src="twitImg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img :src="instaImg">
            </a>
            <a class="img-link" href="[scrubbed]" target="_blank">
                <img :src="yelpImg">
            </a>
            <button id="header-menu-button" @click="toggleMenu">
                <img :src="menuImg">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import logoImg from "../assets/logo/logo_horiz.svg"
    import fbImg from "../assets/social/facebook_blue.svg"
    import twitImg from "../assets/social/twitter_blue.svg"
    import instaImg from "../assets/social/insta_blue.svg"
    import yelpImg from "../assets/social/yelp_blue.svg"
    import menuImg from "../assets/button/menu.svg"

    export default {
        name: 'HeaderBar',
        data: function() {
            return {
                logoImg: logoImg,
                fbImg: fbImg,
                twitImg: twitImg,
                instaImg: instaImg,
                yelpImg: yelpImg,
                menuImg: menuImg
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
#header {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 100;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "logo . menu";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#header.sticky {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#header-logo {
    grid-area: logo;
}

#header-menubox {
    grid-area: menu;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
}

#header-menu-button {
    background-color: unset;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2;
}
</style>
```

Now I have far fewer errors, but the URLs requested look even stranger:
[image: Chrome Console Error Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import them in the javascript portion of the component, then assign them to the element.

Or at least, that's how I got it to work.

```
<template>
    <div id = "imgcontainer"> 
      <img v-bind:src="image"/> 
    </div>
</template>

<script> 
  import img1 from "../assets/1.jpg" 
  export default { 
    data(){
      return{
        image: '', 
      };
    },
    beforeCreate(){
     this.image = img1
    },
  } 
</script>
```

that should solve your problem, in fact, it should solve all of your life problems

Comment: Oh, I see, it looks like the way images are included in components is different than the main app instance. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116796/how-to-import-and-use-image-in-a-vue-single-file-component I'll try it out

Comment: Alright, I'm a lot closer (fewer errors) but it seems to be requesting `/[object Module]` which to me seems even stranger (see post edit). Any ideas?

Comment: Try v-bind:src :D

Comment: `:attr` is shorthand for `v-bind:attr` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands is there a reason you think shorthands shouldn't be used here?

Comment: I tested, `v-bind:src` produces the same result

Comment: It may be your version of webpack, but I'm not sure. Google this:
"[object%20Object] webpack" I'll see if I can help out later when I have free time, unless you say you've found a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I can't nail down a specific issue but there seem to be quite a few that occur when using relative paths with webpack. I tried using `@/assets/` instead of `../assets/` and that didn't work either

Comment: You ever figure it out dude?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190332/discussion-between-735tesla-and-jude-desir).

Answer (score 2):

You should let `webpack` handle this.

Most probably the loader plugin you are using doesn't handle `svgs`.

Check `config/webpack.config.js` or `build/webpack.base.conf.js` and find the rule for images (it should have matches for png, jpeg, gif).

Add `svg` to that regular expression. You'll end up with something similar to this

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
```