# How to include local folder images ( assets ) to vue App

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to add an image , in one of the Vue app , i am using `"./assets/logo.png"`
the url of Vue app is http://localhost:8080/#/

What can be the cause of the error ?

Answers Appreciated

Comment: Can you post a picture of your directory structure? Specifically where the image is stored in relation to the file you are referencing it. Additionally an image or copy of the error will help too

Comment: Structure added , as image please take a look sir.

Comment: Can you show where the image is being used? i.e. the `<img :src="product.image">`

Comment: Please don't post images of code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import and use image in a Vue single file component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116796/how-to-import-and-use-image-in-a-vue-single-file-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to require the image source, add an extra `.` at the start so you go out of the `components` folder, and include `.png` on the end of it:

```
{ ... image: require("../assets/logo.png") }
```

The require is something to do with webpack not knowing where you're referring to without it.

Comment: What if i want to add here - style="background-image: url(./assets/hero-bg.5bbf972f.jpg);">

Comment: Depends where you're using it, CSS/Vue etc., and where the file is located relevant to the image

Comment: I've added like this   <div class="contentone-section section overlay" style="background-image: url(require('../assets/logo.png'));"> & its not working (content not found appears) can you please guide what's missing here ?

Comment: You could bind `style` and use string interpolation: ```:style="`background-image: url(${require('../assets/logo.png')})`"```.

Answer (score 0):

Change `"./assets/logo.png"` to `require('../assets/logo.png')`

This tells Webpack to search for that image at that location and replace the reference with an actual value at render time.

Comment: What if i want to add here - style="background-image: url(./assets/hero-bg.5bbf972f.jpg);">